# Where is solr.xml on datastax 5 (dse)?

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I have dse 5.0 setup with solr and I can't find solr.xml file in solr/home or solr web home.

Where it stores solr.xml on dse ?

Answer (score 0):

See DataStax Enterprise 5.0 documentation, Default file locations...

- [for Installer-Services and package installations](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/install/dsePackageLoc.html):

  - Solr configuration, `/usr/share/dse/resources/solr/conf`
  - Solr configuration files for each node, `/etc/dse-nodeId/solr`
- [for Installer-No Services and tarball installations](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/install/dseTarLoc.html):

  - Solr configuration, `install_location/resources/solr/conf`